# Collision isn't detecting (unity c#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log(other.collider.name);  
    }
```

Is there something wrong with this because it isn't working.
First i tried to run a different code inside the void but it didn't work so i changed it to 
Debug.Log(other.collider.name);
it didn't work too.

Comment: I think you have to post the scene and components image.

Answer (score 0):

this object needs a collider and its collider component needs to collide with something else. also ‘trigger’ must be unselected or else you need to use onTriggerEnter instead of onCollisionEnter.